# Why is my CSS keyframe animation not working?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I found a CSS 'bounce' effect [**here**](http://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp) that I would like to implement in my website: http://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp

I tried copying it as is, and for some reason my web browsers (chrome, firefox and IE) didn't read it. 
I tried working with -webkits and it didn't work either. 
I think there is a specific thing that I am missing that's causing me all of the trouble. 
This is my code, Please help me find a solution!

http://jsfiddle.net/ho7gaywb/

```
    @keyframes(bounce) {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    @include transform(translateY(0));
  }
    40% {
    @include transform(translateY(-30px));
  }
    60% {
    @include transform(translateY(-15px));
  }
}

.bounce{
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s;

}
```

Comment: `@include` is SASS syntax and not pure CSS. Do you have its equivalent CSS?

Comment: ohhhh so that's why! 
no. But it's from the website I posted. 
is there a way to find it there?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7gaywb/1/) is its equivalent webkit syntax :) I hadn't picked it from the other site but it should be the same.

Comment: Nice to know that it helped mate. I am not adding any answer and it is OK if you want to delete the question :)

Comment: Do you maybe know how to make it work on firefox and IE ?
lol I opened my website on IE and it looks like a war-zone XD

Comment: You should replace the `-webkit-` prefixes with `-moz` for older firefox versions or completely remove the prefixes for IE and newer FF.

Comment: `@-moz-keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
 40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
 60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}`


Not working :(

Comment: Wait, Should I totally replace it? 
So it wont work on chrome afterwards..

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ho7gaywb/3/)

Comment: Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ho7gaywb/4/) works in all.

Comment: I understood where was my problem :) 
TNX A LOT !

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to add

   ```
    @-webkit-keyframes(bounce) {0%, 20%, 50%,80%, 100% {
           @-webkit-include transform(translateY(0));   
   }   
     40% {
           @-webkit-webkit-include transform(translateY(-30px));  
    }  
     60% {
           @-webkit-include transform(translateY(-15px));   } }
   ```

   for Mozilla

   ```
       @-moz-keyframes(bounce) {   0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
           @-moz-include transform(translateY(0));  
    }  40% {
           @-moz-webkit-include transform(translateY(-30px));  
    }  60% {
           @-moz-include transform(translateY(-15px));   }
    }
   ```